# get-tagcloud (admin-ajax.php)call is working for administrator accounts but not working for editors account

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin

I have a custom post type (Question) in WordPress. When an editor clicks on "Choose from the most used tags" from add question page, it does not call admin-ajax.php (Same behavior as default post and is working for editor account), but if I log-in as an administrator account, it works fine.

What could be the issue with editor account?

Comment: Posting the jQuery call and the callback php code will be better to get your issue resolved.

Comment: I just need to know, why it is working when I log in with administrator account, the same code is for editor account but it is not working.

Comment: I understand your point but nobody knows what code you are running so nobody can answer without it.

Comment: It is using the wp default code for get-tagscloud